# magic suggest allowDuplicates and clear not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using magicsuggest in my Js file, `allowDuplicates` and `clear` are not working can u please help me??

```
var msf = $('#specific-friends-list').magicSuggest({
            required : true,
            data : '/only/friends',
            minChars : 2,
            valueField : 'id',
            allowDuplicates : false,
            allowFreeEntries : false,
                    });
        msf.clear();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask